# How many moderators should we have?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

While looking at the [election page](https://askubuntu.com/election), I noticed that it states:

> moderator positions available 3

We currently have [four moderators](https://askubuntu.com/about#moderators). So we will lose one moderator spot. How many is right for this community?

Comment: [George made this note](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2408): I'm mentioning this because it was new information to me: apparently if a moderator is elected once, they needn't seek re-election. They are a mod. for life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three is the standard number of community moderators for a launched, public site.

There will be more moderator elections later (typically every year), adding more moderators.

We can also appoint moderators if something urgent happens and a moderator has to step down or take an extended leave of absence.

Answer (score 13):

I brought this up in chat earlier. It went something along the lines of:

- Me: Why are there only 3 positions? Surely we want more than we have now.
- Marco: Current mods aren't that active but I cope.
- Me: True, you are awesome.
- Marco: If we had 3 active mods, it would be easy.
- Me: True

On reflection we do only need a few but for it to be easy as we grow, we need two or three on *all* the time. I do think five is a much healthier number but we have at least a dozen people who are trustworthy enough to have the designation... So why not?

I'm serious. Adding more only makes the job easier.